# error in htaccess not read my images and css file

Tags: .htaccess

i create .htaccess and when run the page all images in my site not display and css not run.

images in the folder (images/) and css in(css/).

another problem the url now is http://localhost/mysite/progams/4

and when click link inside this page will be http://localhost/mysite/progams/program/6

please any one have a solution?

.htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


# Turn on the rewriting engine  
RewriteRule ^program/([0-9]+)/?$ get_programs.php?pack_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^El-Mensajero/?$ home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Daily-Tours/?$ daily_tours.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ get_pages.php?page_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not rewrite static files. Where are your images/css files located?

A rewrite rule like this will prevent files existing on disk not to be rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Do not rewrite static files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Do not rewrite static directories
```

As for your second question, please clarify, im not sure i understand what you mean.